# How to port pure CSS and Javascript to Vue: book flip zIndex transitionend event listener, slow reaction

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I have CSS code with a book with flipping pages, that I'm trying to make work in Vue.

I have two Vue components: `HuhTest.vue` (contains the book) and `HuhComponent.vue` (contains a page). The pages are displayed in `HuhTest.vue` using a `v-for` loop.

The main issue is the Javascript code. Originally, it updates the `translate` and `zIndex` styles of each page, as well as toggles `is-flipped` class. That's something that I managed to make in my Vue version without issue.

However the Javascript code also has `transitionend` event listener, that updates the `zIndex` of each page yet again, once a current page has stopped being flipped. For some reason, in my Vue version there's mistiming which results in wrong page content being displayed, when pages are flipped backwards, and a delay in page content update when pages are flipped forward very fast (meanwhile fast flipping forward works flawlessly in the original code).

I've made two Vue versions: one that works as well as the original: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-violet-wmdt79?file=/src/components/HuhTest.vue, by keeping all the Javascript code unchanged.

And the second version - https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-wing-wjg7jj?file=/src/App.vue.

It's the one I'm trying to fix, that tries to truly delegate the Javascript work to the page components - it has `OohTest.vue` as a book, and `OohComponent.vue` as a page. Flipping pages forward works, but only when done very slowly. Flipping pages backwards doesn't work at all - the content of the displayed pages gets messed up.

Well-working version:

**HuhTest.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div>

  <div  class="book" v-if="this.hasPages" >

    <HuhComponent v-for="(page, index) in this.pages" v-bind:key="index"

                  :front="page.front" :back="page.back"

    />


  </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HuhComponent from "./HuhComponent";

export default {
name: "HuhTest",
  components: {HuhComponent},

  data()  {
    return  {
      pages: [],
      hasPages: false
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.pages = [];

    let total = 5;

    for (let i = 0; i < total; i++)  {
      this.pages.push({
        front: "Front " + i,
        back: "Back " + i
      });
    }

    this.hasPages = true;
  },

  mounted() {
  //alert("mounted");
    this.setup();
  },

  methods:  {
    setup()  {
      const flipbook = (elBook) => {
  const elsPages = elBook.querySelectorAll(".page");
  const totPages = elsPages.length;
  let viewIndex = 0;

  elsPages.forEach((page, idx) => {

    const pageIndex = idx;

    page.style.translate = `${-100 * pageIndex}% 0`;
    page.style.zIndex = totPages - pageIndex;

    page.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
      const isBack = page.matches(".is-flipped");
      viewIndex = isBack ? pageIndex : pageIndex + 1;

      elBook.style.translate = `${viewIndex ? 50 : 0}% 0`;
      page.classList.toggle("is-flipped");
      page.style.zIndex = totPages + viewIndex - pageIndex;

      page.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
        elsPages.forEach((elP, i) => {
          elP.style.zIndex = i < viewIndex ? i : totPages - i;
        });
      }, {
        once: true
      })
    });
  });
};

document.querySelectorAll(".book").forEach(flipbook);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

/* Book */

.book {
  width: 250px;
  transition: 1s;
  perspective: 1500px;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;

 }

</style>
```

**HuhComponent.vue**:

```html
<template>
  <div :class="'page '  ">
    <div class="front">
      {{this.front}}
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      {{back}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "HuhComponent",

props:  {
  front: String,
  back: String,


},


}
</script>

<style scoped>



.page {
  display: flex;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: rotate 1s;
  transform-origin: left center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

}

.is-flipped {
  rotate: 0 1 0 -180deg;
}

.front,
.back {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  user-select: none;
}

.front {
  background-color: orange;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.back {
  background: cyan;
  translate: -100% 0;
  rotate: 0 1 0 180deg;
}
</style>
```

The erroneous version:

**OohTest.vue**:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="book">
      <OohComponent
        v-for="(page, index) in this.pages"
        v-bind:key="index"
        :front="page.front"
        :back="page.back"
        :translate="page.translate"
        :z-index="page.zIndex"
        :index="index"
        v-on:clickEvent="this.clickAction"
        :is-flipped="page.isFlipped"
        :pages="this.pages"
      />

      <!--     <OohComponent front="Front 2" back="Back 2" :z-index="this.pages.length - 0" />
    <OohComponent front="Front 3" back="Back 3" :z-index="this.pages.length - 0"/>
    <OohComponent front="Front 4" back="Back 4" :z-index="this.pages.length - 0"/>
    <OohComponent front="Front 5" back="Back 5" :z-index="this.pages.length - 0"/>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import OohComponent from "./OohComponent";

export default {
  name: "OohTest",
  components: { OohComponent },

  data() {
    return {
      story: null,
      hasStory: true,

      pages: [],
      hasPages: true,

      bookTranslate: "",
    };
  },

  methods: {
    clickAction(index) {
      let page = this.pages[index];

      let viewIndex = page.isFlipped ? index : index + 1;

      this.bookTranslate = `${
        viewIndex && viewIndex < this.pages.length
          ? 50
          : viewIndex === this.pages.length
          ? 100
          : 0
      }% 0`;
      page.isFlipped = !page.isFlipped;

      page.zIndex = this.pages.length + viewIndex - index;

      /*      for (let i = 0; i < this.pages.length; i++)  {
        let page = this.pages[i];
        page.zIndex = i < (this.isFlipped ? this.index : this.index + 1) ? i : this.pages.length - i;

      }*/
    },

    betterSetup() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.pages.length; i++) {
        let page = this.pages[i];
      }

      const flipbook = (elBook) => {
        const elsPages = elBook.querySelectorAll(".page");
        const totPages = elsPages.length;
        let viewIndex = 0;

        elsPages.forEach((page, idx) => {
          const pageIndex = idx;

          page.style.translate = `${-100 * pageIndex}% 0`;
          page.style.zIndex = totPages - pageIndex;
          // alert("some stuff " + idx);

          page.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
            const isBack = page.matches(".is-flipped");
            viewIndex = isBack ? pageIndex : pageIndex + 1;

            elBook.style.translate = `${
              viewIndex && viewIndex < totPages
                ? 50
                : viewIndex === totPages
                ? 100
                : 0
            }% 0`;

            page.classList.toggle("is-flipped");
            page.style.zIndex = totPages + viewIndex - pageIndex;

            page.addEventListener(
              "transitionend",
              () => {
                elsPages.forEach((elP, i) => {
                  elP.style.zIndex = i < viewIndex ? i : totPages - i;
                });
              },
              {
                once: true,
              }
            );
          });
        });
      };
    },

    fakeData() {
      this.pages = [];

      let total = 5;

      for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        this.pages.push({
          front: "Front " + i,
          back: "Back " + i,

          translate: `${-100 * i}% 0`,
          zIndex: total - i,

          isFlipped: false,
        });
      }
    },
  },

  created() {
    this.fakeData();
  },

  mounted() {},
};
</script>

<style scoped>
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  padding: 0.4em 0;
}

/* Book */

.book {
  width: 250px;
  transition: 1s;
  perspective: 1500px;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
```

**OohComponent.vue**:

```html
<template>
  <div
    :class="'page ' + (this.isFlipped ? 'is-flipped' : '')"
    :style="'z-index: ' + this.zIndex + '; translate: ' + this.translate"
    v-on:click="this.$emit('clickEvent', this.index)"
    ref="myPage"
  >
    <div class="front">
      {{ this.front }}
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      {{ back }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "OohComponent",

  props: {
    front: String,
    back: String,

    translate: String,
    zIndex: String,

    index: Number,

    isFlipped: Boolean,

    pages: Array,
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$refs.myPage.addEventListener(
      "transitionend",
      () => {
        this.pages.forEach((page, i) => {
          page.zIndex =
            i < (this.isFlipped ? this.index : this.index + 1)
              ? i
              : this.pages.length - i;
        });
      },
      {
        once: true,
      }
    );
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: rotate 1s;
  transform-origin: left center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.is-flipped {
  rotate: 0 1 0 -180deg;
}

.front,
.back {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  user-select: none;
}

.front {
  background-color: orange;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.back {
  background: cyan;
  translate: -100% 0;
  rotate: 0 1 0 180deg;
}
</style>
```

The `zIndex`, `translate`, `isFlipped` are props in `OohComponent`, which get updated in `OohTest`, which reacts to a `clickEvent` emitted by `OohComponent` when clicked on. The `transitionend` listener is declared once, in `mounted` hook in `OohComponent` - it updates the `zIndex` of each `page` from the given `pages` prop.

I must be doing something wrong, however, since it's not working well.